# open modal only when data is true

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a script where a modal opens up only after the output from python file says dup_yes is 1

I have the modal as following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dupModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" ng-click="save_me()" >Save Me</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="dupModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-alert">Same name already exists</h3>
                <h6 class="modal-ask">Save both entries or do you want to cancel?</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Keep Both</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my script is as follows:

```
$scope.save_me = function () {
    http.get("path to python file").then(function(response){
        $scope.check=response.data;
        if ($scope.check['login_status'] == 1 ){
           console.log("Mission is a Success\n");
           $scope.dup_yes=1;
        }
    })
}
```

When I click on button it opens up the modal and runs the python file simultaneously.

Instead I want it to open up the modal only when my python script gives the value 1.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the modal from the controller and open it like this:

```
$scope.save_me = function () {
   http.get("path to python file").then(function(response){
   $scope.check=response.data;
       if ($scope.check['login_status'] == 1 ){
          console.log("Mission is a Success\n");
          $scope.dup_yes=1;

          var modal = angular.element('#dupModal');
          //modal.modal('hide');
          modal.modal('show');

       }
   })
  }
```

Mayby a better solution is to handle the modal action in a separete controller and inject that into your current controller to keep the responsibilities separate